# How many groups of 4 primes exist such that their sum is a prime and that $p^2+qs$ and $p^2+qr$ are squares?

Tags: number-theory

How many groups of 4 primes of the form $(p, q, r, s)$ exist such that their sum is a prime and that $p^2+qs$ and $p^2+qr$ are both square numbers?

I'm having trouble finding a quadruple satisfying all conditions. I've found a few satisfying the last condition, but they've always failed the first condition. Any help? Thanks!

Can someone give me a start or solution?

Comment: If the sum of four primes is prime it must be odd, so one of the primes must be $2$

Comment: Yes, but that's not the part I'm stuck on. I'm stuck on how to satisfy every condition.

Comment: Is it possible to satisfy all of the conditions?

Comment: $(p,q,r,s)=(2,3,7,7)$ satisfies all given conditions.

Comment: Is that the only one though?

Comment: It appears there are infinitely many solutions with $r=s$. Here are some of them, with $p=2$: $$q=7, \quad r=s=11, $$
$$q=19, \quad r=s=23, $$
$$q=43, \quad r=s=47, $$
$$q=67, \quad r=s=71. $$

Comment: My connection is too rusty to type an answer, but it's worth noting that $p=2$: If $p$ is odd then $p^2\equiv1\pmod{4}$, so for $p^2+qr$ and $p^2+qs$ to be squares we must have either $q=r=s=2$, clearly impossible, or $qr\equiv qs\equiv3\pmod{4}$. Then $q$, $r$ and $s$ are also odd, so the sum is not prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution with $\langle p,q,r,s\rangle$ distinct is $\langle 2, 7, 11, 3\rangle$.

First of all, note that by parity considerations we must have one of the four primes equal to $2$ (otherwise the sum $p+q+r+s$ is even and thus not prime).  What's more, that prime must be $p$; if $p$ were odd, then $p^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$, but then (at least) one of $p^2+qr$ or $p^2+qs$ must be $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ (since mod $4$, it's $1$ plus $2$ times an odd number) and thus can't be a square.  Therefore, $p=2$; I'll omit $p$ in favor of $2$ in what follows.

Next, we know that $4+qr$ and $4+qs$ are both square.  Since they're larger than $4$, they can be written as $(2+a)^2=4+4a+a^2$ and $(2+b)^2=4+4b+b^2$.  Thus we have $qr=a(4+a)$ and $qs=b(4+b)$.  But assuming $a$ and $b$ are different (i.e., $r$ and $s$ are different) then we can take $q=a$, $r=4+a$, $s=b$, $q=4+b$; that is, we have $s$, $q=4+s$, and $r=4+q = 8+s$ all prime.

Now, $s$, $q$, $r$ are three consecutive members of an arithmetic progression with common difference not divisible by $3$, so one of them is a multiple of $3$ and therefore (since it's prime) must be exactly $3$; of necessity this is $s$, the smallest.  This gives $q=7$ and $r=11$, giving the listed solution.

Comment: How do we know $s$ is the smallest? Do you mean it works without loss of generality?

Comment: @Shaun $r$ and $s$ are interchangeable since their usage in the question itself is identical. You're right that there's a 'hidden' WLOG in my answer: it's in the 'But assuming $a$ and $b$ are different' step, where I assign the factors $a$ and $4+a$ of $a(4+a)$ to $q$ and $r$ respectively; if I'd said $q=4+a, r=a$ then we would've had $q=b, s=4+b$ and $r$ would have been the smallest (note that $q$ is always the middle of the progression).

Comment: I think you need to check this bit: "(since mod $4$, it's $1$ plus $2$ times an odd number)" - because it's not $2$ times an odd number, it's an odd number times an odd number. What if $q\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $r\equiv s\equiv 3\pmod{4}$? Then $p^2+qr\equiv p^2+qs\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ can each be a square.

Comment: @Shaun That conditional is under the 'if $p$ were odd' clause; if $p$ is odd, $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$, and $r\equiv s\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then $p+q+r+s$ isn't prime.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $p\le q\le r\le s$. Take
$$
p=2, \qquad q=4k-1, \qquad r=s=4k+3,  \tag{1}
$$
such that $$2+q+r+s \quad \mbox{ is prime. }  \tag{2}$$

Then all given conditions are satisfied because
$$
4 + qr = 4+qs = 4+(4k-1)(4k+3) = (4k+1)^2.
$$
For $p=2$, here are a few $q$ and $r$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$: 
$$q=3, \quad r=s=7, $$
$$q=7, \quad r=s=11, $$
$$q=19, \quad r=s=23, $$
$$q=43, \quad r=s=47, $$
$$q=67, \quad r=s=71. $$
A computer search gives $74$ solutions of the form $(1)$, $(2)$ with $q=r-4$, $r=s<10000$. It is very likely that there are infinitely many solutions of this form. By the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjecture, the numbers $4k−1$ and $4k+3$ are both prime infinitely often.

Comment: what if they are distinct?

Comment: We might try to prove that there are no solutions with four distinct primes.

Comment: are there really none? It doesn't seem likely

Comment: Note that $2+q+r+s=12k+7$, so there are infinitely many values of $k$ for which this is prime by [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: Also, by the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjecture the numbers $4k-1$ and $4k+3$ are both prime infinitely often.

Comment: Cool! That may be useful

Comment: I still can't find a tuple wuth all distinct primes. Are there any?